# Run background-job every hour for n number of times(ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I am using resque for job scheduling. I want to run a job every 1 hour and for N times only. 
I also want to pass count in the job as argument

for example:

```
i=0
50.times do 
   every 1.hour, roles: [:whenever_cron] do
     runner "Resque.enqueue(SomeJob, i+1)"
   end 
end
```

How can I do this?

**Note : -** I don't want to run 50 jobs every hour. I want to run 1 job 50 times

Comment: For count you should need to stored in the database

Answer (score 2):

Scheduling syntax is for *recurring* jobs. Those that happen over and over again, until the end of times.

For single-shot jobs, you enqueue them, with an optional delay (which is what you need here). So you can just enqueue the whole batch of your jobs all at once, with 1 hour increments:

```
1.upto(50).each do |x|
  Resque.enqueue_in(x.hours, SomeJob)
end
```

Comment: ❤ this is a perfect example of an X/Y problem.